# Глаголы прожить/ждать переходные или непереходные?

Tags: морфология, глаголы

Читаю учебник "Русский язык 5-9 класс. Теория. Углубленный курс" про переходные и непереходные (параграф 75). Там пример:

> Мы прожили зиму в деревне.

Указано, что в данном предложении сказуемое (прожили) выражено непереходным глаголом:

[image]

Читаю [вики словарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):

> про-жи́ть
>
> Глагол, совершенный вид, переходный, тип спряжения по классификации А.
>   Зализняка — 16b/c[①]. Формы с ударением на последние слоги (прожи́л,
>   прожи́ло, прожи́ли, прожи́в) считаются разговорными. Соответствующий
>   глагол несовершенного вида — проживать.

Тоже самое касается и глагола "ждать".

Среди авторов учебника Вера Васильевна Баба́йцева (13 октября 1925, СССР — 10 февраля 2016, Москва) — советский и российский лингвист, доктор филологических наук, профессор. Автор множества научных работ, вузовских и школьных учебников. Основатель структурно-семантического направления в российской лингвистике. [Подробнее на вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0,_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Так переходные данные глаголы или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это переходные глаголы, они допускают прямое дополнение.

Обратите внимание, что глагол "ждать" чаще требует не винительного, а родительного падежа (Чего ты ждёшь?).

> Жизнь прожить - не поле перейти.
>
> Аист с нами прожил лето, а зимой гостил он где-то. (С.Маршак)
>
> Обещанного три года ждут.
>
> Жду ответа, как соловей лета.

Вы привели два аргумента в пользу переходности этих глаголов и ни одного - против. Почему вы сомневаетесь?

Answer (score 1):

Переходными называются глаголы, обозначающие действие, которое направлено на объект, выраженный зависимым именем в форме вин. п. (при наличии в предложении отрицания такой вин. п. регулярно заменяется род. п.: читал книгу – не читал книги).

В вашем примере зависимое слово при глаголе "прожить" находится в винительном падеже и является дополнением, а не обстоятельством, как написано в учебнике. Это говорит о переходности глагола.